# criticar erro quando CEP for invalido (via CEP )

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá!

Estou utilizando o código abaixo para obter endereço através do CEP informado.

Funciona, porém ao digitar um CEP invalido ou 0000000, obtenho o retorno `{"erro":true}`.  Como eu posso transformar este retorno num alert com o código abaixo:

```js
 console.log("webservice cep");
 
 $("#numero").attr("readOnly", true);
 $("#complemento").attr("readOnly", true);
 //var lastCepCheck = '';
 var ultimo_cep = '';
 document.getElementById('cep').addEventListener('keyup', function() {
     //Impede inserir algo alem de Números
     //this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/, "");

     //Pega apenas os números
     var cep = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/, "");

     //Só pesquisa se tiver 8 caracteres e o ultimo cep pesquisado seja diferente do atual.
     if (cep.length != 8 || ultimo_cep == cep) {
         return false;   
     }
     ultimo_cep = cep;

     ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

     var url = "http://viacep.com.br/ws/" + cep + "/json/";
     ajax.open('GET', url, true);
     ajax.send();

     ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
   //console.log(ajax.status);
         if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
             var json = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);    
             console.log(ajax.responseText);
    if (json == "{erro: true}"){
     alert("erro");
    }
    else {
    $("#logradouro").val(json.logradouro);
    $("#bairro").val(json.bairro);
    $("#cidade").val(json.localidade);
    $("#uf").val(json.uf);
    $("#numero").attr("readOnly", false);
    $("#complemento").attr("readOnly", false);
    $("#numero").focus();
             }
         } 
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode existir outros métodos mais simplificados, mas desta forma também funciona. Basta você converter para String o retorno do erro que está em JSON e fazer a verificação:

```
if (JSON.stringify({erro: true}) == '{"erro":true}')
  alert("erro");
```

**Editada:**

```
if (JSON.stringify(json) == '{"erro":true}')
  {alert("erro");}
```

Comment: Obtenho isto: `Uncaught TypeError: json.stringify is not a function
    at XMLHttpRequest.ajax.onreadystatechange`

Comment: Se você descomentar a linha `//console.log(ajax.status);`, qual código mostra? Se for diferente de 200, nem vai passar pela verificação do erro.

Comment: exibe codigo 200

Comment: Consegue descobrir o nome da propriedade que retorna o erro? No caso é só substituir. `if (json.propriedade.stringify({erro: true}) == '{"erro":true}')
  alert("erro");`

Comment: Tente também: `if (JSON.stringify(json) == '{"erro":true}') alert("erro");`

Comment: Perfeito, veja como ficou!
`if (JSON.stringify(json) == '{"erro":true}') {alert("erro");}`

Comment: Atualiza a resposta para eu marca-la!
Obrigado!!

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/215227/revisions

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a função `hasOwnProperty()` para verificar se existe o indice "erro" no valor retornado pela `API`;

```
var json = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);
if (json.hasOwnProperty('error')) {
    console.log(json.error);
}
...
```